# Complete embeddings into $Fn(\kappa \times \omega, \omega)$

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

I have problems to show the following: 
Let $\kappa$ be a regular uncountable cardinal, $\lambda < \kappa$ and let $\mathbb{P}=Fn(\kappa \times \omega, \omega)$, $\mathbb{Q}=Fn(\lambda \times \omega, \omega)$ and $\mathbb{R}=Fn(J,\omega)$. $J= \{\alpha : \lambda \leq \alpha < \kappa \}$. Show that each of the posets $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ completely embeds into $\mathbb{P}$. 
My problem is that i don't know how to show that. 
The case for $\mathbb{Q}$ seems trivial since $\lambda < \kappa$. But is it really that trivial? 
I have no idea how to show that $\mathbb{R}$ completely embeds into $\mathbb{P} $. 
 
**Definition** 
For an infinite index set $I$ we defined $Fn(I,\omega)$ as the partial order of all finite partial functions $p:I \rightarrow \omega$ with extension relational superset.

Comment: Step 1: write the definition of "completely embeds". Step 2: Verify the obvious thing works. Step 3: Tattoo on your forehead "always start with the definitions". Step 5: Look in the mirror and figure out you should have tattooed that mirrored. Okay, maybe only steps 1 and 2.

Comment: My idea for the first case is the following:
$i: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}$, $i(p)=p$, so $i$ is just the identity.
Therefore it is order preserving and preserves incompatibility. 
And for the last condition: let $q \in \mathbb{P}$, then $q |_{(\lambda \times \omega)}$ is a reduction of $q$ to $\mathbb{Q}$